# How would i set the height and width of dynamic images

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

This is working fine and giving me the images but these images are of different resolution and i want all of them to be of 200x200

HTML

`<div class="container-fluid" id="myElement"> 
<div id="images"> </div></div>`

Javascript function

```
function appendReturnedImages(data) {


  $.each(data.images, function(index, element) {

    $("#myElement #images").append($('<img height="200" style="max-width: 200px">', {

      src: element

    }));

 });

}
```

Comment: And what's the question? and do not append in a loop!!!

Comment: How would i set the height and width of dynamic images

Comment: How can i resize image to 200x200

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I said earlier, **do not append in a loop** as it's expensive! The cleaner and correct way to append is as below.

```
var $html = $();

$.each(data.images, function(index, element) {
    $html = $html.add($("<img/>", {
        height: 200,
        //width: 200, // uncomment this if you need to set width as well
        css: {
            'max-width': 200
        },
        src: element
    }));    
});
// You shouldn't be using $("#myElement #images") as an ID must be unique in a document!
$("#images").append($html);
```

Comment: how can i do same thing with videos?

Comment: Not sure what you meant. Try a similar approach or post another question.

Comment: i mean to say if there were videos instead of images what would be my approach?

Comment: HTML 5 videos can do the job

Answer (score 0):

If image isn't in ratio 1:1, you can't show it in resolution 200x200px without deforming. HTML can't show just a part of image, always the whole.

You need to prepare thumbnails 200x200 and use them, or set image to background for element with size 200x200px.

Comment: all i can do to solve this thing using code. Because images are coming from server.

Comment: @AbdurRehmanFarooqi: okay, than: HTML nor CSS can't to crop image. Just show it in correct ratio, or deform it. Not crop or show just a part.

Comment: @AbdurRehmanFarooqi: read once again what I've written a min ago. Than create on server thumbs of correct size and link them. What you want isn't possible with your images.

Answer (score 0):

shouldn't this line:

```
$("#myElement #images").append($('<img height="200" style="max-width: 200px">', {
```

look like this?:

```
 $("#myElement #images").append($('<img style="width: 200px; height: 200px;">', {
```

Comment: Yes, But images are not displayed in this way.